# What is the differece between Make Library Override and Add Library Override?

Tags: interface, blend-files

Blender 2.81 came with Library Override. We have Make Library Override in the Object menu. And we have Add Library Override in the Outliner.

What is the differece between Make Library Override and Add Library Override? Is this same functionality with accidentally two differente names? Or is there a difference in the behaviour?

For example, the entry in the Object menu is greyed out, the one in the outliner not. For a reason?

[image]

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the technical details, the main difference seems to be that the *Object > Relation > Make Library Override* is iterating through the entire hierarchy and overrides everything that is necessary, while the function for the outliner is for a single data block. This is documented in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html)

Comment: Perfect. This is what i was looking for. Thanks. Could you please make it an answer? Then i can upvote it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html) the operator from the outliner *ID Data > Add Library* (`bpy.ops.outliner.id_operation(type='OVERRIDE_LIBRARY)`) is for overriding a single data block.

> **Single Data-Block Override**
>
> You can override a single data-block from two places:
>
> - The Outliner (it’s in the context menu of IDs), in which case all local usages of that linked ID will be remapped to the new local override.
>
> [...]

On the other hand *Object > Relation > Make Library Override* (`bpy.ops.object.make_override_library()`) iterates through the hierarchy of objects and collections based on the selection, overriding everything linked.

> **Make Library Override Operator**
>
> This one operates in the 3D View, over linked objects or local empties instantiating a linked collection (typically, a linked character). It is very similar to the Make Proxy operator, and is found in the same sub-menu `Object ‣ Relations ‣ Make Library Overrides…`.
>
> Unlike the method described above, it will go through the whole hierarchy of collections and objects, and override all those needed to allow posing/animation of a character.
>
> **Note**
>
> Proper Collections Layout Matters
>
> For this operator to work properly, it is crucial that all the collections needed by the character are children of the root (linked and instantiated) one. Otherwise, some won’t be automatically overridden, and manual work will be needed to fix the override.